# Database Error Occured

Tags: mysql

Error Number: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') and qbank.institute_id ='1' ORDER BY FIELD( qid, )' at line 1

```
SELECT * FROM `qbank` JOIN question_category ON qbank.cid = question_category.cid WHERE qbank.qid IN ( ) and qbank.institute_id ='1' ORDER BY FIELD( qid, )
```

The Following is the Complete Code:

```
function get_question($rid){
 $institute_id = $this->session->userdata('institute_id');

    $query = $this -> db -> query("select quiz_result.* from quiz_result where rid='$rid' and institute_id='$institute_id'");
    $row=$query->row_array();
    $qids=$row['qids'];

    $query = $this -> db -> query("SELECT * FROM  `qbank` JOIN question_category ON qbank.cid = question_category.cid WHERE qbank.qid IN ( $qids ) and qbank.institute_id ='$institute_id'  ORDER BY FIELD( qid, $qids )");
    $questions=$query->result_array();
    $query = $this -> db -> query("SELECT * FROM  q_options WHERE qid IN ( $qids )  and institute_id = '$institute_id'");
    $options=$query->result_array();
    $dataarr=array($questions,$options);
    return $dataarr;
  }
```

Comment: Look at the final, generated query and you'll see what the problem is - `$qids` is empty.

Comment: Change to prepared statments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare below statement and share prepared statement/query to check exact issue-

```
SET @qry=CONCAT("SELECT * FROM qbank JOIN question_category ON qbank.cid = question_category.cid WHERE qbank.qid IN ( ",$qids,") AND qbank.institute_id ='",$institute_id,"' ORDER BY FIELD( qid, ",$qids,")")
```

Possible reasons: You are passing your argument values in invalid format.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 syntax errors.

1. you can't have an empty list ()
2. you have a commma in the order by without a field. (qid, )

Comment: This is the complete query;- "SELECT * FROM  `qbank` JOIN question_category ON qbank.cid = question_category.cid WHERE qbank.qid IN ( $qids ) and qbank.institute_id ='$institute_id'  ORDER BY FIELD( qid, $qids )");